# Custom JSF EL function, date converter and current component

Tags: jsf, el

We use bookmarkable URLs and GET methods.

We have some parameters which contains dates and are converted using the default DateTime converter.

```
<f:viewParam name = "parameter" value  = "#{model.parameter}" converter = "javax.faces.DateTime" />
```

This works flawlessly and parameters are converter to and from String

When we have to generate links (e.g., with `<h:link>`) to these pages we need to convert  `Date` parameters to a correctly formatted string (as the `<f:param>` tag does not support a converter). The default format of `Date.toString()` will not be parsed by `javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter`.

I came up with the following solution but I have the feeling the it could be done more elegantly.

I defined a custom EL function `convertDate`

```
<f:param name="parameter" value="#{ func:convertDate( model.someDate, component ) }" />
```

with the following implementation

```
public static String convertDate( Date date, UIComponent uiComponent )
{
    DateTimeConverter dateTimeConverter = new DateTimeConverter();
    return dateTimeConverter.getAsString( FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), uiComponent, date );
}
```

The idea is to use the default `javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter` to convert the date but I need a reference to the corresponding `UIComponent`.

Does the usage of `#{component}` make sense? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTimeConverter` uses [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) under the covers. You might want to use it instead so that you can get rid of the `#{component}` argument.